# Microsoft .net framework versions and subversions

Tags: .net, frameworks, versions

I am new to an organization that has several hundred .net applications, dlls, etc that have been written over the last 15 years.  When I run powershell scripts or ILdasm to see the framework version that the exe, dll, etc. is targeting, I often get frameworks that look like they have sub versions.  Thus instead of seeing v2.0, for example, I will see v2.0.50727

My questions, in general are:

1. Did Microsoft put out different .net frameworks with subversions.  So instead of see just a major version, such as 2.0, we might also see 2.0.50727 and 2.0.111 and 2.1.123, and so on?
2. If they did put out different sub versions, it seems like I would need to have dozens of different frameworks installed on my development machine to update older systems (assuming I didn't want to update the frameworks they targeted), instead of just having major framework versions.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Not counting the now irrelevant .NET 1.x versions, there have only ever been two runtime versions.  2.0.50727 and 4.0.30319.  You cannot have dozens of framework versions installed on your machine.  Only two.  When you keep your machine updated by letting Windows Update do its job that will be 3.5 SP1 and 4.6.1 right now.  They are backwards compatible with earlier revisions, of which there are too many to count.  Lots of revisions to fix bugs and security issues.  Not keeping machines updated is a mistake.

Comment: U useful link I found adding a little more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2007/12/06/versions-of-microsoft-net-framework-clr-and-your-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

Additional thought...

Since any later framework on a computer will support any targeted framework (in the code) earlier than framework on the box, as long as the framework on the computer is higher than the one targeted in the code, it will work.

So if a computer has Framework 4.0 installed, it will support applications that target 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.5, 4.0, etc.

However, that still leaves the question of whether framework 4.0 on a box will support version 4.0.227 (a hypothetical version that may or may not exist).

Comment: I bet you did not visit Wikipedia to check the .NET Framework version history. The CLR version remains the same, 2.0.50727, or 4.0.30319. Microsoft will not break that rule. But the fourth digit can change to reflect the revisions.